# imageErrorBuilder not invoking when image URLs are broken

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using the FadeInImage widget to load network images along with imageErrorBuilder. But, in some cases, imageErrorBuilder isn't working. Below is my source code.

```
FadeInImage(
            placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/placeholder.png'),
            imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
              return Image.asset('assets/placeholder.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
            },
            image: NetworkImage(url!),
          )
```

I'm getting exceptions as given below.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: NetworkImage is an empty file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/assets/mainnet/95KN8q3qubEVjPf9trgyur2nHx8T5RCmztRbLuQ5E5i/logo.png

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following HttpException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Connection closed while receiving data, uri = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/b0e47e39f84cffb655f406eb569c57a88b5211cc/assets/mainnet/FnKE9n6aGjQoNWRBZXy4RW6LZVao7qwBonUbiD7edUmZ/logo.png
```

Does anyone suggest to me how to handle these types of cases?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you the path to the error image is correct?

Comment: It seems correct, do you have the latest version of flutter?

Comment: @Supertommino I'm using Flutter 3.3.0

Comment: @hamzat_yhs Yes, I've checked. It's all set up.